# How to use a vector in lag operation in R

Tags: r, lag

In R, How do we use a vector instead of element in the lag function. i.e for Lag(x,k=2); instead of 2 I want to use a vector because I want to lag each row by a different value. So one row could have a lag of 3, while 1 could be 0 etc.

Example:

```
a #lags d
1 0     1 
2 1     1
4 2     1
3 0     3
1 1     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you may need to write your own function for this task. i wrote one that i think will be what you need, or perhaps point you in the right direction:

```
x1 <- c(75,98,65,45,78,94,123,54) #a fake data set for us to lag
y1 <- c(2,3,1,4,1,2,3,5) #vector of values to lag by

#the function below takes the data, x1, and lags it by y1

dynlag <- function(x,y) {
a1 <- x[length(x)-y]
return(a1)
}

#test out the function

dynlag(x1,y1)
```

hope this helps. :)

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted. Needed to tweak it as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with index calculus:

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'a lags d
1 0     1 
2 1     1
4 2     1
3 0     3
1 1     3')
i <- seq(length(D$a))
erg <- D$a[i - D$lags]
all.equal(erg, D$d)
```